# Nginx redirect and geolocalization

Tags: nginx, redirection, geolocation, geoip

I've the following problem with Nginx and GeoIP and will be nice if you can give me some pointers about the solution.

*Note: I know this can be solved on DNS side, but that won't be possible by now so I'm looking for other solution.*

**The problem**
My www.domain.com has 1.1.1.1 IP address located in Amazon running Nginx with a redirect like this:

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://2.2.2.2
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

On 2.2.2.2 there's another nginx using geoIP. The problem is that all my clients seems to come from 1.1.1.1, as 2nd nginx is geolocating by `$remote_addr`.

Is there any way to catch real client IP ($remote_addr on 1.1.1.1) and pass it as a different variable to 2.2.2.2 and use it on geolocalization?

Any tip, comment or RTFM is welcome. I'll keep looking for a solution to try to answer this question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your upstream nginx, use the [RealIpModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRealipModule) to get the real IP out of the `X-Forwarded-For` header that you are sending from your downstream nginx.

For example:

```
server {
    set_real_ip_from 1.1.1.1;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your help. This solved the issue!